# Efficient way to present and frequently change images on android app?

Tags: android, view, memory-management, repaint, power-management

I have several imageViews in a layout.
Frequently, (5-10 sec) I want to have some of the images change (use another source).

Since I am only a beginner with android, energy-wise does using an imageView makes sense for my purpose?

Is there a more a efficient way, to present several images that are going to change frequently?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView` makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

Well in that case I recommend to go with a TimerTask and in that task get the instance of the `ImageView` and call the `setImageDrawable()`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) class to animate between different [ImageViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) at a specified interval.